# Executing query as part of a SQL job

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using the following query to insert data into a table:

```
INSERT salesteamactivity.dbo.ProfileScore
    SELECT
        DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS [Date],
        owneridname AS [Account Manager],
        COUNT(new_cyberessentialsname) AS [Cyber Essentials],
        COUNT(sec1_encryption) AS [Encryption],
        COUNT(sec1_firewallsolutionname) AS [Firewall],
        COUNT(sec1_pcidss) AS [PCI DSS],
        COUNT(sec1_asvscannername) AS [PCI ASV],
        COUNT(sec1_pentestingname) AS [Penetration Testing],
        COUNT(new_phishinsolution) AS [Phishing],
        COUNT(sec1_scannername) AS [Scanner],
        COUNT(sec1_twofactorauthentication) AS [Two Factor Authentication],
        COUNT(1) AS [Relationship Type]
    FROM 
        [SEC1_MSCRM].dbo.[FilteredAccount]
    WHERE 
        customertypecodename = 'Customer' 
        AND statuscodename = 'Active'
    GROUP BY 
        owneridname
```

If I run the task as a standalone query the data is inserted as expected. If I run it as a step in a SQL Server Agent Job the data doesn't insert although the script parses and the job completes with success.

Attached are a couple of screenshots for the job config.

Step configuration:

[image]

General configuration:

[image]

Regards

Comment: What if you create a stored procedure and execute it from the job?

Comment: Could be an access right issue. Try to select a user that can insert in the table in the run as list option.

Comment: @DoubleT28 I tried a couple of users, mine included given that it allows me and still nothing. Job executes stating success but no data is inserted.

Comment: Hi @jonny I created the sp, it still has the same result. Executes stating success but draw no data through.

Comment: The problem could be due to the fact that the two tables you are using in this statement are in two separate databases. Could you try to copy the FilteredAccount table in the SalesTeamActivity database to test ?

Comment: @DoubleT28 it does work if I execute the sp in a query against the table. Its only when I execute the sp from a Scheduled Job that it fails to get data

Comment: I managed to solve this one. The source for my SELECT data was a Microsoft CRM 2013 View. There are permissions in the view that specifically limit Jobs from running without using `EXECUTE AS` to specify the account the query runs under or by another method. The simplest route is to gather the data from the TABLE rather than the VIEW and then work the data back into a readable format.